# K9-like program that blocks websites?

Tags: internet, parental-controls

In windows there is a very good program which block inappropriate sites
called K9 web protection I was wondering is there a program like that or a good option to block inappropriate sites?

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Ubuntu specific, but another option is setting your DNS server to OpenDNS with settings to block inappropriate sites.  See [this guide via Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110806020149/http://getparentalcontrols.org/2008/01/01/review-opendns-adult-site-blocking/).

**Remarks**: Original link is no longer accessible. Even the archived guide is outdated; OpenDNS settings have since changed for free usage, according to [this page](https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/?url=familyshield).

Comment: Link is dead. Can you provide an alternative (or better yet, write an answer that handles the configuration)?

Comment: Updated link to archived page via Wayback Machine. Also note that OpenDNS settings have since changed (perhaps answerer or someone else could improve the answer later).

Answer (score 0):

it is not the perfect solution but I used a firefox extension called [ProCon Latte](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1803/) and for now it works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Another OS independent option is DynDns's free Internet Guide.  More information can be found here: http://www.dyndns.com/services/dynguide/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one recently, its an easy to install & use proxy server with parental controls built in , you can even set time periods in which internet access will be blocked. It can perform https filtering and can block pages based upon the presence of user specified keywords either in the page content or the url . I've made the binaries freely available to download and use over at my [website](http://gatesentryfilter.abdullahirfan.com). This project has evolved from the project GateSentry for the Raspberry Pi  which was a full blown linux image that did the same thing. [I made it completely open source back in 2015](https://github.com/fifthsegment/gatesentry). Some of the features of the new project include :

- Built-in Web based User interface: GateSentry comes with its own web based interface which is powered by React and can be easily viewed via any modern desktop/mobile browser.
- HTTPS Filtering (via MITM)
- Built-in User authentication system: GateSentry comes with a built in user authentication system where you can add more users/delete users, disable their internet access. If not required on your network you can disable the user authentication system too.
- Time based Internet Access
- Content type blocking : blocking allows you to block specific file types on your network. Want to disable images? simply add the mime "image/png" and "image/jpeg" to GateSentry.
- Data Consumption Statistics: If the user based authentication system is enabled GateSentry shows the amount of data consumed by each user on your network.
- Remotely Disable User access: Access for network users can be easily enabled or disabled with a single click from the User Management Panel.