# Internet filter for Ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parental controls with different settings for different users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users)

is there anti filter program for internet and some websites in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and there is even a page on the Ubuntu wiki about this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContentInternetFiltering

From that page I took the names and added a link where you can learn more about this:

1. ContentInternetFiltering/Willow: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContentInternetFiltering/Willow
2. DansGuardian: http://dansguardian.org/
3. SquidGuard: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquidGuard