# How do I allow a user to login only every other day?

Tags: login, parental-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parental controls with different settings for different users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users)

I would like to allow a user to login every other day, but how would I go about doing that? I would like it to involve as little regular action from me as possible. I tried timekpr but that doesn't have the functionality and I don't know any other way. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain, what you want to restrict? I use timekpr and you can restrict all day at once or each weekday seperatly?
Maybe you can try timeoutd or gnome-nanny.

Comment: See the answer about Nanny http://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users The answer includes a picture I'd believe you are asking for (?)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).