# Is there any "windows-family-safety"-like feature available in Ubuntu?

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)
>   [What is the best way to restrict access to adult content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content)

Is there any "windows-family-safety"-like feature available in Ubuntu? I tried OpenDNS but it is not good at all. It is not able to stop nonsense images (and at times videos) brought  up by search engines, for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time) - see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users and http://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i could find except of OpenDNS is [DansGuardian](http://dansguardian.org/) but its bit more complicated to work wit as Windows Family Safety.

Comment: Thankx, but dansguardian blocks some essential links as well.