# How to permanently, unfixably disable wireless internet?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, internet, live-cd

I have a problem with internet addiction. (Yes, really.) I have internet access on my cellphone, which I don't abuse, but having internet on my laptop basically makes me completely non-productive.

In the past I fixed this by going into /sbin and doing `rm iw* if*`, which makes it impossible to get internet back because to get those files back needs a liveCD and to get a liveCD requires internet; I gave a liveCD copy to a responsible friend in case of emergency.

However, I recently got a new laptop and upgraded to 12.10. I'm having trouble completely disabling the wireless. I tried removing `nt-*` but this had no effect - the applet is gone, but the laptop still automatically connects. I tried removing `iw* if*` and `/usr/sbin/NetworkManager`, but after doing that and rebooting, Xorg mysteriously just blackscreened, so I had to use a liveCD to copy the files back. X now works, but I still have internet access.

All help appreciated :)

Comment: Remove the wireless adapter and give it to your responsible friend.

Comment: Have you considered going to a therapist rather than searching for a technical solution to a non-technical issue?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/647/44179

Comment: I think you should switch to 12.04 since 12.10 has alot of internet intergration....

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, a **friend** could blacklist all drivers for the inbuilt wireless capability for this specific laptop. They would then provide you with a user account that does not have rights to undo this.

*However, you could always re-install the OS, find another wireless device, or simply find some other method ..*

---

If this is a serious addiction, you will NOT be able 'cure' yourself without ongoing counselling and the support of family and friends. It is highly unlikely that anyone can provide a simple technology-only solution.

**You may need to EITHER revert to the earlier setup (11.04) OR give up the laptop all together.**