# Can you set up parental controls?

Tags: parental-controls

I know this is a rlly dumb question (sorry) but is there a way to set up parental controls on my ubuntu 14.04 computer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not much alive I am afraid. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content http://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time or https://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users. Many projects were discontinued or don't work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo the best options are opendns

For information see http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/

You can also filter google search results.

The problem with such tools has always been the lack of a consensus on the filter list.

Good luck to you